# Getting error in scrapy web crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Hi I tried to implement this in my code.But I am getting the following error: `exceptions.NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined`.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class spider_aicte(BaseSpider):
    name = "Indian_Colleges"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.domain.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.domain.org/appwebsite.html",
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            download_link = link.get('href')
            if '.pdf' in download_link:
                pdf_link = "http://www.domain.org" + download_link
                print pdf_link
                class FileSpider(BaseSpider):
                    name = "fspider"
                    allowed_domains = ["www.domain.org"]
                    start_urls = [
                            pdf_link
                            ]
        for url in pdf_link:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def save_pdf(self, response):
         path = self.get_path(response.url)
         with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should import [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) before using:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
```

---

Or, there is also a "shortcut" import:

```
from scrapy import Request
```

Or, if you have `import scrapy` line, use `scrapy.Request`.